# Retrieving values from a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

I have stored a string in the format `<td> value1 </td> <td> value2 </td> <td> value3 </td>` into a JavaScript variable. How can I get the values `value1`, `value2`, and  `value3` and store these into an array using jQuery?

Comment: You probably mean "Web Programmer"...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Why do you think this requires jQuery at all? Where did the string come from? Perhaps you could store it in the right format from the outset.

Comment: @Matt Ball I tried `.find('<td>')`. String is coming from a table row when a user selects a row

Comment: It's not exactly the same as that question. The other version is more generic whereas my question is more specific. Please read both questions and see the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Tadeck's solution, I've decided to go more functional-style:

```
var values = $('<td>value1</td><td>value2</td><td>value3</td>')
  .filter("td") // optional
  .map(function(){return $(this).text()})
```

Answer (score 1):

Roughly like that:

```
var values = [];
jQuery('<td>value1</td><td>value2</td><td>value3</td>').each(function(){
    values.push(jQuery(this).text());
});
```

In more details:

- by `jQuery(some_html_string)` you convert `some_html_string` into DOM elements (enclosed in `jQuery` objects), that then can be used for processing in jQuery,
- `some_elements.each(callback)` executes `callback` on every element of `some_elements`,
- `some_element.text()` fetches text from within the element (`some_element`),
- `some_array.push(some_value)` pushes `some_value` into the `some_array` array,
- at the end, `values` should contain text values from the elements enclosed in the string,

Comment: The first argument in the anonymous function is the index, not the element. While the second argument is the element, it's not a jQuery object, so `.text()` won't work on it.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: I did not check the solution, missed that mistake. Now it is corrected, thanks.